# Can a non-logical operator be used between salary range and Equity?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, user-experience

On Jobs listings and search results, there is sometimes green text indicating a salary rage and or Equity next to the title.  In the case where there is both, the pipe (`|`) is used to separate the entries. Such as:

[image: Data Engineer listing with Pipe]

Coincidentally, the pipe is used in may programming contexts to denote ***or***. I don't see both very often, and maybe it is just a peculiarity of my mind, but when I do see both I usually end up paused wondering if the pipe means *Or* such that the pay will be less if you take an equity option.  I really don't think the listing is trying to convey that much information, but would there perhaps be another way to present this information?

I don't have a strong suggestion for a better alternative, but I tested a couple just to ensure something other than the pipe has potential to work.

em-dash:
[image]

space: [image]

color and space: [image]

Comment: I find it hard to believe many programmers would be confused by the pipe simply because *in a programming context* it denotes an or. Your first alternative could be viewed as subtraction as well. Would that mean the salary is 70k minus whatever equity they over?

Comment: Perhaps not, this is after all just a suggestion based on sample size 1 (me). I can't say I'm at all likely to mistake an em-dash with subtraction: there is significant difference in width.

Comment: I can't imagine a lot of people interpreting this as a logical operator rather than a design element either. But maybe I'm just not enough of a hardcore programmer. :)

Answer (score 6):

It's a bitwise OR, so you get the salary bits and the equity bits.

Comment: if only I knew how these appear in the registers :)